# Сериализовать в json класс и подкласс

Tags: c#, json

```
    public class ОбщиеНастройки
    {
    public IList<Настройка1> Настройка1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Настройка1
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }
        public string Addr { get; set; }
    }
```

Как правильно сериализовать чтобы получился json файл:

```
ОбщиеНастройки:
  Настройка1
    Поле1
    Поле2
```

Сейчас создаю экземпляры через new, но и записывается в json или в класс ОбщиеНастройки, или содержимое настройка1. Как их объединить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить вот такое решение

```
[Serializable]
public class Base
{
    public ОбщиеНастройки ОбщиеНастройки { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ОбщиеНастройки
{
    public IList<Настройка1> Настройка1 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Настройка1
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public string Addr { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var common = new Base
        {
            ОбщиеНастройки = new ОбщиеНастройки() 
            { 
                Настройка1 = new List<Настройка1>() 
                {
                    new Настройка1() { Title = "Title", Alias = "Alias" },
                    new Настройка1() { Title = "Title1", Alias = "Alias2" }
                }

            },
        };

        var serializedObject = serializer.Serialize(common);
    }

}
```

Результат работы
[[image: Результат работы[1]]